# How to give members access to their own protected page?

Tags: user-access, membership, content-restriction

I'd like to give each member access to their own personal page that only I'll be able to edit. Each member will have their own personal page with private info.

Do you have any suggestions on how to do this? Thank you!

Comment: you want page in backend like profile page of wordpress or in front end ?

Comment: I'd like the page to be in the frontend.

Comment: create page with wp_insert_post, give some template to the created page and on that template you can do whatever you want e.g showing user related data, like showing username id etc

Answer (score 0):

```
funtion add_profile_page(){ 
    $title_of_page = "page name";
    if( null == get_page_by_title( $title_of_page ) ) {
            $post_id = wp_insert_post(
                array(
                    'comment_status'    =>  'closed',
                    'ping_status'       =>  'closed',
                    'post_author'       =>  '1',
                    'post_name'         =>  'namehere',
                    'post_title'        =>  $title_of_page,
                    'post_status'       =>  'publish',
                    'post_type'         =>  'page'

                )
            );
            update_post_meta($post_id, '_wp_page_template', 'mycustomprofile');
        }  
}

add_filter( 'after_setup_theme', 'add_profile_page' );
```

your template page

```
/*
    Template Name : mycustomprofile
*/


// Do whatever you want here
```